# Why is there no display until I press Control-Alt-F1?

Tags: nvidia, hdmi

When my machine boots into ubuntu I get "no signal" in my monitor until I press Control-Alt-F1. This makes the login screen appear and everything is normal. But why do I have to press it?

Some notes

- Control-Alt-F2 doesn't work. My googling tells me that these commands normally change to a virtual terminal, but that doesn't appear to be the case on my system.
- My monitor is [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B08PFMN3CL/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) which is sold as a smart TV rather than a monitor.
- My version is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- My graphics card (in case that helps) is  8GB NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 3050 - HDMI, DP, LHR
- On boot, the monitor wakes up to show me the bios and let me select which operating system it wants. Then it loses signal again until I press the key combination.
- On very random occasions the screen does work normally, I'm trying to isolate when those are...
- Booting into windows has no problems at all.

EDIT -

some extra notes:

- For the last few weeks the drivers for my graphics card haven't been working and it was defaulting to llcm - during that time there were no problems with display when booting, but I also couldn't wake the machine from sleep at all.  Now that I've fixed the graphics card, this problem has come back.

Comment: This may be due to several things (and I always find it difficult when this happens to me). Possibilities I encountered: graphics driver did not load, the HDMI port did not signal the connection of the monitor after the monitor being in standby, wrong refresh rate configured.

Comment: @Sascha - those are all interesting - I'm keen to work out tests I could run that would confirm or eliminate one of the options?

Comment: How did you find the key combination?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I wish I could tell you.  I was scrabbling around various blogs and forums from like three different machines...

Comment: Unhelpfully this has change recently. Now it works fine for startup but not restoring from sleep?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Ctrl+Alt+F1 is the default key combination to return to gnome login screen after using any of the virtual consoles (Ctrl+Alt+F3...F7). The Ctrl+Alt+F2 takes you to the running GUI session if there is one.