# Blackscreen after splashscreen ubuntu 23.10 nvidia graphicscard

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, 23.10

## Black screen after Spashscreen on boot

Every time i start or reboot my PC i et runs through the boot process and after the splash screen the screen goes black. It should have shown the login screen but it doesn't.

If if press `<CTRL><ALT><f1>` it some how refreshes and now the login screen shows.

I have tried setting the nomodeset in grub, but this doesn't help.
I have tried reinstalling nvidia drivers, to no luck.
I have tried installing the newest nvidia-550 drivers that are not yet shipped with ubuntu, but i could not get them to work.

## System Details Report

---

### Report details

- **Date generated:**                              2024-01-24 20:53:06

### Hardware Information:

- **Hardware Model:**                              Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Z790 AORUS ELITE AX
- **Memory:**                                      32.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   13th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-13600KF × 20
- **Graphics:**                                    NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3070
- **Disk Capacity:**                               2.1 TB

### Software Information:

- **Firmware Version:**                            F2
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 23.10
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               45.2
- **Windowing System:**                            X11
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.5.0-14-generic

## grub file

```bash
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# If your computer has multiple operating systems installed, then you
# probably want to run os-prober. However, if your computer is a host
# for guest OSes installed via LVM or raw disk devices, running
# os-prober can cause damage to those guest OSes as it mounts
# filesystems to look for things.
#GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you're not booting to text? Check [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859630/how-to-start-ubuntu-in-console-mode#859637) for details on what to check and how to switch back. From a user68186 comment in a [similar thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1473725/why-is-there-no-display-until-i-press-control-alt-f1#comment2598357_1473725): > Ctrl+Alt+F1 is the default key combination to return to gnome login
> screen after using any of the virtual consoles. It sounds like this might be happening, so possibly you're booting to a console mode. Since you are otherwise

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. it doesn't seem like i'm booting into text. I have updated the question with my grub file.